# BufferedReader adds endlessly on readLine()

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I'm trying to send test messages from Arduino via bluetooth by spamming "hello world!" every 100 ms.
Now, on android I've got an endless addition of "hello world!" to my StringBuilder  and each debug iteration I have "hello world!\nhello world!\nhello world!\n..." etc.
What should I do? 
As an idea I will spam a lot of Jsons from arduino to Android device. Do I have to make some special char sequences for dividers to break the while after each message from arduino? Or is there a simpler decision?

```
 public static String toString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

            byte[] bs = new byte[inputStream.available()];
            if (Utils.isZero(bs.length)) {
                return "";
            }
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while (r.ready()) {
                line = r.readLine();
                total.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            return total.toString();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break the while"? "dividers"? Right now you have a `StringBuilder` (not a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html?) containing multiple "lines" of text, which seems not bad, so why change it? Also, you should keep the scope of 'line' inside the loop; outside is too broad. I assume the lack of a close or exception handling are for brevity. The use of 'available()' is unnecessary and a bit risky. Mixing bytes and chars is risky. What is it about what you have now that you do not like?

Comment: StringBuilderObj.setLength(0) to clear if thats what you are trying to do.. Your problem is very vague

Comment: I said I spam messages from arduino, and it's an endless InputStream. Endless. it always adds and adds and adds to it. It will never end

Comment: So why therefore are you trying to accumulate it all in a `StringBuilder` before you return from this method? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking for end of stream.

The correct way to write that read loop is:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    total.append(line).append('\n');
}
```

But if the data is endless it doesn't make sense to even have a loop. Just return `br.readLine()`. It doesn't even make sense to have this method.

NB You don't need to allocate a byte array just to determine its length.

Comment: there is no ending to the end of stream. it is being constantly added on the other end. that is the problem. it never leaves the loop.

Comment: So you should process the data inside the loop instead of afterwards, or not have a loop in this method at all, and call it in an outer loop..